# Change mailx mailbox location

Tags: mailx

On my computer, mail is stored in `~/Mailbox`, not in a centralized directory. Is there a way to get `bsd-mailx` to read mail from there, instead of looking in `/var/mail`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the location of the mailbox in two ways. The first is using the MAIL environment variable:

```
export MAIL=$HOME/Mailbox
```

The other method is to use the `-f` option to mailx to specify a mbox file manually:

```
mailx -f ~/Mailbox
```